# Generate inserts from an Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sqlplus

I want to generate the insertions of a table using 'sqlplus' and I do not know how to do it. Does anyone know? I have also tried using the command 'exp', with the following statement:

```
exp user/password@server file=data_table.dmp buffer=10485867 statistics=none tables='name_table'
```

but it does not work either. It generates a .dmp file that I can not use. I want it to generate INSERTS.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer `SELECT /*insert*/ * FROM table_name` and F5 (run as a script)

Comment: I can not use SQL Developers, that's the problem. It must be from the command terminal

Comment: [SQLcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592148/oracle-export-select-statement-result-set-as-insert-sql-statements-similar-to#38593502)