# Deleting data from two linked tables

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I've got two tables called Patient and Account.
Patient has PatientID as it's PrimaryKey. Account has AccountID as PK and PatientID is a Foreign Key and also has treatmentDate as a tuple.

I want to delete all patients that have not had an account since 2005.
this is what I've got:

```
DELETE FROM PATIENT
WHERE PATIENTID IN (
  select account.PatientID
  from ACCOUNT
  where Treatmentdate < '01-JAN-2005' );
DELETE FROM ACCOUNT
WHERE PATIENTID IN (
  select account.PatientID
  from ACCOUNT
  where Treatmentdate < '01-JAN-2005' );
```

is there any other way in which I can do this?

Comment: found this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485581/generate-delete-statement-from-foreign-key-relationships-in-sql-2008/2677145#2677145)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather use the

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

option in the Foreign Key PatientID of the ACCOUNT table.

In this case you wouldn't need the second query.

See for reference (there's plenty of info in the net):
[SQL ON DELETE CASCADE, Which Way Does the Deletion Occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444859/sql-on-delete-cascade-which-way-does-the-deletion-occur)