# Order change in Parent to its child tables using FK relations

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have used [Aasim Abdullah's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485581/generate-delete-statement-from-foreign-key-relationships-in-sql-2008) stored procedure to dynamically generate code for deletion of child tables, based on parent with certain filter condition. But I am getting a output which is not proper (Query 1). I would like to have output mentioned in Query 2.

--[Patient] is the Parent table, [Case] is child table and [ChartInstanceCase] is grand child
--When I am deleting a grand child table, it should be linked to child table first followed by Parent

**Query 1**

```
DELETE Top(100000) FROM [dbo].[ChartInstanceCase]
FROM [dbo].[Patient] 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Case]              ON [Patient].[PatientID]        = [Case].[PatientID]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ChartInstanceCase] ON [ChartInstanceCase].[CaseId] = [Case].[CaseID]
WHERE [Patient].PracticeID = '55';
```

**Query 2**

```
DELETE Top(100000) [dbo].[ChartInstanceCase]
FROM  [dbo].[ChartInstanceCase] 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Case]    ON [ChartInstanceCase].[CaseId] = [Case].[CaseID] 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Patient] ON [Patient].[PatientID]        = [Case].[PatientID]
WHERE [Patient].PracticeID = '55';
```

Please let me know how I should modify the SP `dbo.uspCascadeDelete` to get the output as Query 2?

Comment: The *textual* ordering of tables within a query is largely irrelevant. So far as I can see, the two queries are "the same" from an information perspective and should have identical effects.

Comment: And what is wrong with the first?  Post the stored procedure you need help with - don't expect us to get look it up.