# How to generate Delete statement from Foreign Key Relationships in Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Can someone suggest a way to generate delete queries for various tables linked via foreign key constrains for Oracle ? A solution for SQLServer is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485581/generate-delete-statement-from-foreign-key-relationships-in-sql-2008)

Copied description from the original question :

> I have the table: DelMe(ID) and there are 30 tables with fk references
>   to its ID that I need to delete first, is there some tool/script that
>   I can run that will generate the 30 delete statements based on the FK
>   relations for me ?

Comment: Maybe a stupid answer, but you might consider defining the FKs with cascade delete.

Comment: @RobertKock : Actually as it happens in most of such cases, I do not have the luxury to update the schema as its a legacy application that we need to support.